# Why is it showing 'None' as an output for my function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a function `accordian(l)` that takes as input a list of integer `l` and returns `True` if the absolute difference between each adjacent pair of elements strictly increases.

```
def accordian(l):

    for i in range(len(l)):
     diff = []
     for i in range(len(diff)):

             diff = l[i] - l[i+1]
             if diff[i] < diff[i+1]:
                     return True
             else:
                     return False

print(accordian([1,3,7,2,9]))
```

Output: "None"

Comment: `diff` is empty, giving you nothing to iterate over, meaning your returns are still not reached.

Comment: You have to replace `for i in range(len(diff)):` with `for i in range(len(l)):` otherwise your function will never get to a `return`.
Also I guess it should be `diff[i] = l[i] - l[i+1]` instead of `diff = l[i] - l[i+1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because the inner loop never runs, since the length of `diff` is 0, however a range of `0` doesn't proceed, your code will work if you add a value to `diff`, I can't give a code since I don't fully understand what you wanna do.

Comment: Answer is still getting None

Comment: Sorry, there were some minor changes, could you check the code again?

Comment: Thanks, everyone! Btw question was Write a function expanding(l) that takes as input a list of integer l and returns True if the absolute difference between each adjacent pair of elements strictly increases.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
def accordian(data):
    diff = []
    for index, value in enumerate(data):
        if index == 0:
            continue
        diff.append(data[index] - data[index - 1])

    flag = True
    for index, single_element in enumerate(diff):
        if index == 0:
            continue
        if diff[index] <= diff[index - 1]:
            flag = False
            break
    return flag


print(accordian([1, 3, 7, 2, 9]))
print(accordian([1, 3, 7, 13, 21]))
print(accordian([1, 3, 5, 7, 9]))
```

Output:

```
False
True
False
```

Comment: @Shallum : As this answer solved your problem. Please accept the same.